# AndroidEntryPoint not working with AbstractComposeView

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel, dagger-hilt

I am using DaggerHilt for dependency injection. In my AbstractComposeView, I need to access the ViewModel in a Composable function. To do that I have to annotate my AbstractComposeView with @AndroidEntryPoint, since my Composable is part of the AbstractComposeView (which is being used in a Service with @AndroidEntryPoint). but I am getting this error.

```
error: [Hilt]
  The base class, 'androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView', of the @AndroidEntryPoint, 
'com.qwillio.vendi.keyboard.presentation.KeyboardView', 
contains a constructor with default parameters. 
This is currently not supported by the Gradle plugin. Either specify the 
base class as described at https://dagger.dev/hilt/gradle-setup#why-use-the-plugin 
or remove the default value declaration.
  [Hilt] Processing did not complete. See error above for details.
[Hilt]
```

This is my AbstractComposeView

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class KeyboardView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : AbstractComposeView(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private var keyboardActionListener: OnKeyboardActionListener? = null

    fun setOnKeyboardActionListener(keyboardActionListener: OnKeyboardActionListener) {
        this.keyboardActionListener = keyboardActionListener
    }

    @Composable
    override fun Content() {
        Vendiboard {
            keyboardActionListener?.onKeyboardAction(it)
        }
    }
}
```